# How to solve "docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error"

Tags: linux, git, docker

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://github.com/uzh-rpg/flightmare/tree/ddc_challenge. It seems I have correctly installed the docker engine on Ubuntu, as the `run hello-world` image works correctly.

However, on step 4, when I run `docker run -it -v path_to_dodge_drone_challenge_folder:/root/challenge/ --rm --runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all  -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254 --name ddc-challenge uzhrpg/dodgedrone-challenge:base /bin/bash` on the terminal, I receive the following message:

```
 docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/db25c7005bad4fbd08c557a4ea487b8bdafbfe243ad5821a59e24d715f08107e/log.json: no such file or directory): fork/exec /usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime: no such file or directory: <nil>: unknown.
```

This is muy docker version

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:18:05 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:16:00 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. I have already try to reinstall everything.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Is docker running?

Comment: @KamilCuk no, it is not running. When I start it running using `docker run -a stdin -a stdout -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash`  and then write  ```docker run -it -v path_to_dodge_drone_challenge_folder:/root/challenge/ --rm --runtime=nvidia -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all  -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254 --name ddc-challenge uzhrpg/dodgedrone-challenge:base /bin/bash```, the message received is
```bash: docker: command not found```

Comment: Is the docker _service_ running? Run `sudo systemctl start docker`. Follow a docker installation tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @KamilCuk I follow some tutorials and yes, my docker service is running as I have seen using `docker info`. However I still have the same problem I comment on the post when following step 4 of the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on nvidia Xavier and I solved it by installing nvidia-container-runtime. As you are also using the nvidia-runtime I guess this might also solve your problem: `sudo apt install nvidia-container-runtime`

Answer (score 0):

The error message points that `/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime` does not exist. It would seem your installation is missing that runtime as you are selecting it with the `--runtime` option. Look to install the nvidia docker runtime in your system, thre are plenty of articles about it in a quick search.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @miguelbernadi , I've followed your indications. However, now I get a different message when following the step 4 of the tutorial:  `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:495: container init caused: Running hook #1:: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: failed to process request: unknown.` Any idea?

Comment: Seems the runtime is now being found. It seems the runtime complains about an error in the driver. May it be you need the proprietary driver from Nvidia and you are using the reverse engineered one? Maybe the driver is not loaded properly or missing some library? We are no longer looking at a problem with Docker itself, but the GPU support from Nvidia. Is the graphics card manufactured by Nvidia?